# Ambassador shows no healthy upstream

Tags: kubernetes, ambassador

I have setup Kubernetes in CentOS with 1 master and a separate node. Added Ambassador GW and later a service with mapping. When I try to access the end service using the GW mapping it responds with `no healthy upstream` message.

Comment: This might be better handled on the [Datawire OSS Slack](https://d6e.co/slack), where there's an `#ambassador` channel. At minimum, it would be useful to see the `Mapping` in question...

Answer (score 5):

In my case the mapping was right but the service was actually in different namespace than Ambassador. I was missing the `.namespace` in the service name:

So change the service from
`service: <service.name>`
to 
`service: <service.name>.<namespace>`