# Ambassador Edge Stack w/ GKE Health Check and LB Provisioning Errors

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, ambassador

I'm currently installing the Ambassador Edge Stack (AES) to help manage several applications running applications in our GKE cluster but I'm experiencing a couple of issues.

The steps in [the manual install guide](https://www.getambassador.io/docs/edge-stack/latest/topics/install/yaml-install/) seem to be working fine aside from `edgectl` being deprecated in favour of `telepresence` (I haven't tried this out really).

The next steps, [setting up the ingress with GKE](https://www.getambassador.io/docs/edge-stack/latest/topics/running/ambassador-with-gke/) is where the issues begin.

As per the guide, this can be done with the legacy Ambassador API Gateway or the new AES.  Doing a compare of both installs, you don't need to do anything in the API Gateway install other than sorting out patching [the original](https://www.getambassador.io/yaml/aes.yaml) aes `ambassador` service and the `ambassador-admin` service from `LoadBalancer` to `NodePort` types. I've done this with `kustomize`

```
# prod/ambassador-service-patches.yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ambassador
  namespace: ambassador
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"8080": "my-backend"}}'
spec:
  # loadBalancerIP: 35.244.139.65
  type: NodePort # needed for GKE ingress LB
  ports:
   - name: backend
     port: 8080
     targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ambassador-admin
  namespace: ambassador
spec:
  type: NodePort # needed for GKE ingress backend health check
  ports:
   - name: backend
     port: 8877
     targetPort: 8877
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ambassador
  namespace: ambassador
spec:
  replicas: 3

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ambassador-agent
  namespace: ambassador
spec:
  replicas: 3
```

The rest is all about setting up the GKE `Ingress` and `BackendConfig`. Mine look like this:

```
# prod/ingress.yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: my-cluster-ssl
spec:
  domains:
    - www.mydomain.com
---
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-backend
  namespace: ambassador
spec:
    timeoutSec: 30
  connectionDraining:
      drainingTimeoutSec: 30
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 10
    timeoutSec: 10
    healthyThreshold: 2
    unhealthyThreshold: 2
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /ambassador/v0/check_ready
    port: 8877
  logging:
    enable: true
    sampleRate: 1.0
 ---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: ambassador
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "my-global-ip"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "my-cluster-ssl"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: ambassador
    servicePort: 8080
```

This is where things start falling apart. The `ambassador` and `ambassador-admin` services and pods run fine. The `Ingress` creates an `HTTP` LB with assigning my reserved global ip address and a fails to get an OK from the backend health checks. I believe because the LB is HTTP and is not exposing port 443 the the `ManagedCertificate` also fails to provision with the `NOT_VISIBLE` error.

Doing some troubleshooting I've added now a `FrontEndConfig` and added to to my ingress with the annotation `networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: "my-frontend"` to setup a HTTP redirect LB but this new redirect only LB is assigned the global static ip address (not the HTTPS LB) which has `This load balancer has no frontend configured`. Below is the `FrontendConfig`.

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: FrontendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-frontend
  namespace: ambassador
spec:
  redirectToHttps:
    enabled: true
```

I've also played around with a `kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"` with no luck. This ingress+backend+frontend config isn't that different from what I used to have except the Ingress spec mapped to the individual services I needed, without any issues.

At this point I've been at it for a couple days and looking for some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the google documentation, if you want the load balancer to terminate SSL traffic then you need to configure it to do so. You can use the following instructions: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls

These are linked to in the original documentation by google about how to create a L7 loadbalancer as linked in the ambassador docs: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer (link comes from Step 1 of this site you linked: https://www.getambassador.io/docs/edge-stack/latest/topics/running/ambassador-with-gke/)

Unfortunately this means that you wouldn't be getting full advantage of Ambassador's letsencrypt automatic certificate generation when you specify both an ambassador `Mapping` and a `Host`. On my GKE cluster which I installed AES from scratch, has a `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` which automatically creates a google load balancer (if you're in GKE that is). This service has ports configured for 443 and 80 automatically and no additional ingress is needed.

Comment: The setup you linked (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) is exactly how I had my cluster setup originally before Ambasasdor. This worked fine even with managed certs.

I'm okay using Ambassadors lets encrypt feature. I think this was working before but I didn't deploy the Host and Mapping manifests.

Comment: is there a way to assign the ambassador service LB a static IP?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. I ended up using the Ambassador LB and using the automated LetsEncrypt feature

Comment: For added context I had to also add the namespace to the service.See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240636/ambassador-shows-no-healthy-upstream.

I wonder if that would of got the GCP LB setup working?

Comment: The LB IP that gets generated is technically static until you delete the LB. I don't think there's a use case for specifying the IP addr of the LB. I don't think you really specified the errors/issues that you were seeing only that there were issues so I dont' think I can answer your last comment.